# Error customizing validation error messages in JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

I've followed the steps answered in similar SO questions and also in other sites like [Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/) with no success. I'm describing below what I've done so far in order to customize the `javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED`:

1. Create `MyMessages.properties` in `formularis.utils.missatges.custom` package and customize the error:

   ```
   javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = This value is required.
   ```
2. Copy `MyMessages.properties` and translate to my languages:

   ```
   MyMessages.properties
   MyMessages_ca_ES.properties
   MyMessages_es_ES.properties
   MyMessages_en_US.properties
   ```
3. Declare the properties file in `faces-config`:

   ```
   <application>
       <locale-config>
           <default-locale>ca_ES</default-locale>
           <supported-locale>ca_ES</supported-locale>
           <supported-locale>es_ES</supported-locale>
           <supported-locale>en_US</supported-locale>
       </locale-config>
       <message-bundle>formularis.utils.missatges.custom.MyMessages</message-bundle>
   </application>
   ```

Am I missing any configuration or declaration? I don't understand why my application doesn't show my custom error messages. Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you get any errors in the log or console?

Comment: Nope. It shows the default error message `form_id:component_id: Validation Error: Value is required.`, not my customized message.

Comment: @jmrodrigg Have you placed your property file in your Container's `config` folder ?

Comment: The tutorial link in your post is for JSF 2.0, not for JSF 1.2.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can't it be applied to JSF 1.2? I've been reading different articles that suggest this same idea and I would say I've read some of them referring to JSF 1.2. At least they don't specify that the solution only works for JSF 2.0 and above. If you confirm that, I would give up trying this solution... but can you suggest any approach that would not represent a manually change in every component?

Comment: @VikasV No, the property file is located inside my webapp as I only want to customize my webapp's error messages.

Comment: @jmrodrigg Ok. Can you please post your code where on using the JSF component you are trying to print this customized error. For eg., `<h:inputText validator="#{yourBean.yourMethod} requiredMessage="">`
I have this customized error message which works in JSF 1.2, but here I have placed the property file in Container's config folder. I never gave a try by not placing it there